# How do I select only a specific digit from the MNIST dataset provided by Keras?

Tags: python, filter, keras, deep-learning, mnist

I'm currently training a Feedforward Neural Network on the MNIST data set using Keras. I'm loading the data set using the format

`(X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = mnist.load_data()`

but then I only want to train my model using digit 0 and 4 not all of them. How do I select only the 2 digits? I am fairly new to python and can figure out how to filter the mnist dataset...

Answer (score 17):

`Y_train` and `Y_test` give you the labels of images, you can use them with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to filter out a subset of labels with 0's and 4's. All your variables are numpy arrays, so you can simply do;

```
import numpy as np

train_filter = np.where((Y_train == 0 ) | (Y_train == 4))
test_filter = np.where((Y_test == 0) | (Y_test == 4))
```

and you can use these filters to get the subset of arrays by index.

```
X_train, Y_train = X_train[train_filter], Y_train[train_filter]
X_test, Y_test = X_test[test_filter], Y_test[test_filter]
```

If you are interested in more than 2 labels, the syntax can get hairy with where and or. So you can also use [`numpy.isin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) to create masks.

```
train_mask = np.isin(Y_train, [0, 4])
test_mask = np.isin(Y_test, [0, 4])
```

You can use these masks for boolean indexing, same as before.

Answer (score 1):

you have the label files along with train and test:

```
train_images = mnist.train_images()
train_labels = mnist.train_labels()

test_images = mnist.test_images()
test_labels = mnist.test_labels()
```

you can use them together with a simple list comprehension to filter your dataset

```
zero_four_test = [test_images[key] for (key, label) in enumerate(test_labels) if int(label) == 0 or int(label) == 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

using `Y_train = Y_train[train_mask]` raises `InvalidArgumentError` when the digits aren't consecutive and start with 0 (keras expects a consecutive label range starting from 0)

the solution (for two digits) is:

```
train_mask = np.isin(Y_train, [2,8])
test_mask = np.isin(Y_test, [2,8])

X_train, Y_train = X_train[train_mask], np.array(Y_train[train_mask] == 8)
X_test, Y_test = X_test[test_mask], np.array(Y_test[test_mask] == 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
# Filter images of digit three
X_digit_three = train_X[train_y == 3]
```

If you want their index:

```
idx_3 = np.where(train_y == 3)[0]
```